# Как сделать выборку из базы данных с двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу вывести на страницу всех пользователей, у которых установлен аватар.

Запись о пользователях хранится в таблице `user`, об аватаре - `gallery_foto` (`avatar = 1` - значит, аватар есть)

Пытаюсь это сделать так:

```
$avatar = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gallery_foto` WHERE `avatar` = '1' LIMIT 1"));
$koll = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE pol <> '".$user['pol']."' AND '".$avatar['id']."' = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");


    while ($uss = mysql_fetch_assoc($koll))
{

///тут вывод рользователей

}
```

но выводятся и с аватаром, и без.

В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, корректный SQL-запрос должен выглядеть так:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user u
JOIN gallery_foto gf ON (u.user_id = gf.user_id AND gf.avatar = 1);
```

Либо же так:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user u, gallery_foto gf
WHERE (u.user_id = gf.user_id AND gf.avatar = 1);
```

(в обоих вариантах `*` при необходимости заменить на требуемые поля)

**Примечание:** `user_id` в данном случае — идентификатор пользователя (предполагаемое общее для обеих таблиц поле — должно присутствовать для корректного объединения таблиц): в вопросе было ничего не сказано о нем, поэтому вам требуется самостоятельно подставить подходящие для вашего случая наименования.

[Основанный на данных запросах пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/942f0/2) (с некоторыми изменениями)

[Почитайте](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) об использовании `JOIN` в SQL

---

Исходя из этого, php-код будет примерно следующим:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user u
JOIN gallery_foto gf ON (u.user_id = gf.user_id AND gf.avatar = 1)");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     // вывод строк из результата SQL-запроса
}
```

[Информация о функции `mysql_fetch_array()` с неплохими примерами](http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql-fetch-array)

**Дополнительно:** ваш код беззащитен против [SQL-инъекций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Экранируйте информацию, которую включаете в запросы к БД.

Comment: Простите, не могли бы вы написать полный код запроса, исходя из моего кода?

Comment: @Денис, добавил предполагаемый php-код и ссылку на мануал.